# Oracle SQL Client Inactivity query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create a query that shows the client ID, the longest time in between files being received for each client, and how long it has been since the last file received.

The information I have is all in one table that holds filenames, time/date the file was received on, the client ID for that file, and multiple other unrequired columns.

the end result I am looking for is essentially a row for each client ID, then the max time between files being sent for that client within the last year, and then time since the last file was received.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What have you tried? We're not really here to wrtie your code for you from scratch. Can you at least show the table schema, sample data, and expected results for that data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `lag` to get the previous date, then `group by` to find the maximum difference:

```
with y as (
    select
        client_id,
        received_date,
        lag(received_date, 1) over (
            partition by client_id 
            order by received_date
        ) as prev_date
    from
        x
    where
        received_date >= sysdate - interval '1' year
) select
    client_id,
    max(received_date - prev_date) as max_duration_days,
    max(received_date) as last_received_date
from
    y
group by
    client_id;
```

[Example SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2a9d83/7)